# Converting DATE and TIME integers to timestamp

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, datetime, cast

I am trying to get a timestamp by combining date and time columns in my PostgresQL database and am running into errors. Here is what I have:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| StartDate | StartTime |
+-----------+-----------+
| 20210301  | 18000000  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 20210302  | 19000000  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 20210303  | 20000000  |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Here is what I want

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
| StartDate | StartTime | StartStamp            |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 20210301  | 18000000  | 2021-03-01 18:00:00.0 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 20210302  | 19000000  | 2021-03-02 19:00:00.0 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 20210303  | 20000000  | 2021-03-03 20:00:00.0 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

In MySQL I would be able to get this by using the following sql

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(concat(LPAD("STARTDT", 8, '0'),'-', LEFT(LPAD("STARTTM", 8, '0'),6)),'%Y%m%d-%H%i%s') AS StartStamp
From Table1
```

To get that in Postgres, I've tried `CAST(STARTDT as DATE)` but that resulted in an error. I've tried `TO_DATE()` but that also did not work. Is there a way to get the timestamp in PostgreSQL?

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`to_timestamp()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) with an appropriate [format template](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE).

For string input, with padding to the left like in your example:

```
to_timestamp(lpad("STARTDT", 8, '0')
          || lpad("STARTTM", 8, '0'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSMS')
```

For `integer` input, this should be most efficient:

```
to_timestamp(lpad(("STARTDT" * bigint '100000000' + "STARTTM")::text, 16, '0') , 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSMS')
```

Produces `timestamptz` (based on your current `timezone` setting). A plain cast to `timestamp` gets the according local `timestamp`:

```
to_timestamp( ... )::timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you!, That worked